# how to commit "FieldGroup" drupal module setting

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have `Drupal 7` site. It has Content type `Product` which has 25+ fields. So I used `FieldGroup` contributed module to group the fields.

Grouping & Validation everything working fine. 
My question is 
 
How to commit these settings into svn?

I mean other developer working on the application, if  checks out the latest code, they must get the form with field grouping.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module allow configuration export in code and supports Field Groups.